# utilizing check boxes and radio buttons to narrow down combo box search results?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a nested IF statement that I wanted to rely on two sets of radio buttons to populate combo box list based on two separate worksheets. If an employee is in-seat, then allow the user to search an employee either by name or by their ID. Same goes for termed employees. the userform isn't allowing me to have two sets of radio buttons being applied, so i had to incorporate check boxes, too.

```
Private Sub chkInSeat_Click()
    Call LoadEmployee_Cmb
End Sub
Private Sub chkTermed_Click()
    Call LoadEmployee_Cmb
End Sub
Private Sub optInSeat_Click()
    Call LoadEmployee_Cmb
End Sub
Private Sub optTerm_Click()
    Call LoadEmployee_Cmb
End Sub

Sub LoadEmployee_Cmb()
    Dim isWs As Worksheet: Set isWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("In Seat")
    Dim tWs As Worksheet: Set tWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Terms")
    If UserForm1.chkInSeat.Value = True Then
        If UserForm1.optEmployeeName = True Then
            For x = 2 To isWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem isWs.Cells(x, 4) & " - " & isWs.Cells(x, 1)
            Next x
        ElseIf UserForm1.optEmployeeID = True Then
            For x = 2 To isWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem isWs.Cells(x, 1) & " - " & isWs.Cells(x, 4)
            Next x
        End If
    ElseIf UserForm1.chkTermed.Value = True Then
        If UserForm1.optEmployeeName = True Then
            For x = 2 To tWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem tWs.Cells(x, 4) & " - " & tWs.Cells(x, 1)
            Next x
        ElseIf UserForm1.optEmployeeID = True Then
            For x = 2 To isWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                UserForm1.cmbEmployee.AddItem isWs.Cells(x, 1) & " - " & isWs.Cells(x, 4)
            Next x
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and it should be populate the combo box, but it results in this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can add non-contiguous data to a combobox (I might be wrong). I would suggest creating and filling an array for your data then loading the array into the combobox. https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/how-to-populate-combobox-vba-userforms/

Comment: If you place each set of radio buttons inside a frame, they will behave as you desire.

Comment: @BrianMStafford this was the solution I was looking for, thank you!!!